# Getting DOM-Element without knowing anything about it

Tags: javascript, dom

i want to access an html element of a response from some web site. I already turned the string into an html object like this:

```
let el = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, "text/html");
```

The thing is that I cant use an id or class or anything to identify this element. The only thing I have is a path of how to get to that element. For example:

```
["body", "div::2", "div::1", "div::0", "div"]
```

I've been trying to do that like this:

```
        let el = doc;
        for(let i = 0; i < (path.length); i++){
            if(path[i].includes('::')){
                [elname, index, ...rest] = path[i].split('::');
                el = el.querySelectorAll(':scope > '+elname)[index]
            }else{
                elname = path[i];
                el = el.querySelectorAll(':scope > '+elname)[0]
            }
        }
```

but it is giving me a hard time because i dont know why but I found out that the response of my get request differs from what i see in my browser. Some elements just dont show. So it fails almost every time because some element is not at the spot it is supposed to be at. Is there maybe something wrong with my code or does anyone maybe have a better alternative?

Thanks is advance for the help :)

Comment: "*The only thing I have is a path of how to get to that element.*" - is that path necessarily in that format?

Comment: "*i dont know why but I found out that the response of my get request differs from what i see in my browser*" - that's nothing to do with the path access code you posted. Yes, you first will need to figure out why you are getting different responses, and then either fix your requests or find a way to deal with the difference.

Comment: you're right :/

Comment: the path is always the same format. I'm getting the path of an element using my chrome extension and then i try only using the path and the url to get that same element. On some web sites this works (stack overflow is no problem) but on others some div in between is just missing which makes my path basically useless...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to create an xpath query and use that
Xpath is a language to query an xml or html document, if you could compute an query for xpath to use you chan then use this query as selector.

[https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp]